# Communicating between Java SSLSocket and HTML5

Tags: java, html, ssl, websocket

Just a quick question, can I use SSL in html5 with websockets to communicate with my java server that is using SSLSockets?

I have been trying to connect using another java client using ssl sockets, which works, but I have not tried to do it through html5. Is it even possible?

For the record, I am using github pages to host my server, and I have a custom domain provided by Namecheap and an SSL certificate from Comodo.

Is it even possible to communicate between java and html5 using SSL?

Answer (score 2):

WebSockets are not the same as "normal" TCP sockets but instead a protocol layer on top of TCP. And thus WebSockets over SSL can not communicate directly with SSLSockets. To communicate with WebSockets (with or without SSL) you would need a [library implementing the WebSocket protocol](https://www.google.com/search?q=websocket+java).

Comment: To use websockets over SSL, do I need to have a SSL certificate for my site? Because that is not possible with Github unfortunately. But I will take a look into some Websocket Libraries.

Comment: @KobeyRafferty: to use anything with SSL the SSL server must have a certificate (except for some special use cases like anon-DH). This is needed to for server authentication which is needed to protect against man in the middle attacks.

Comment: Okay thanks. Appreciate it, will look into installing a SSL certificate with github.